# Understanding ordering within a graph when doing traversals

Tags: data-structures

I'm trying to understand depth first and breadth first traversals within the context of a graph.  Most visual examples I've seen use trees to illustrate the difference between the two.  The ordering of nodes within a tree is much more intuitive than in a graph (at least to me) and it makes perfect sense that nodes would be ordered top down, left to right from the root node.

When dealing with graphs, I see no such natural ordering.  I've seen an example with various nodes labeled A though F, where the author explains traversals with nodes assuming the lexical order of their label.  This would seem to imply that the type of value represented by a node must be inherently comparable.  Is this the case?  Any clarification would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node values in graphs need not be comparable.

An intuitive/oversimplified way to think about BFS vs DFS is this:

- In DFS, you choose a direction to move, then you go as far as you can in that direction until you hit a dead end.  Then you backtrack as little as possible, until you find a different direction you can go in.  Follow that to its end, then backtrack again, and so on.
- In BFS, you sequentially take one step in every possible direction.  Then you take two steps in every possible direction, and so on.

Consider the following simple graph (I've deliberately chosen labels that are not A, B, C... to avoid the implication that the ordering of labels matters):

```
Q  -->  X  --> T

|       |
|       |
v       v

K  -->  W
```

A DFS starting at Q might proceed like this: Q to X to W (dead end), backtrack to X, go to T (dead end), backtrack to X and then to Q, go to K (dead end since W has already been visited).

A BFS starting at Q might proceed like this: Q, then X (one step away from Q), then K (one step away from Q), then W (two steps away from Q), then T (two steps away from Q).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIA8HEEUxZI) wherein the author chooses which adjacent node to visit next based on the label of the node, which is what led to my confusion.